# Uri.AbsolutePath messes up path with spaces

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, system.net, winapp

In a WinApp I am simply trying to get the absolute path from a Uri object:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(myPath); //myPath is a string
//somewhere else in the code
string path = myUri.AbsolutePath;
```

This works fine if no spaces in my original path. If spaces are in there the string gets mangled; for example 'Documents and settings' becomes 'Documents%20and%20Setting' etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
LocalPath instead of AbsolutePath did the trick!

Comment: note to all: this is a rare display of encoding ignorance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's encoding it as it should, you could probably UrlDecode it to get it back with spaces, but it's not "mangled" it's just correctly encoded.

I'm not sure what you're writing, but to convert it back in asp.net it's Server.UrlDecode(path). You also might be able to use LocalPath, rather than AbsolutePath, if it's a Windows app.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're writing, but in asp.net it's Server.UrlDecode(path);

Comment: You also might be able to use LocalPath, rather than AbsolutePath, if it's a Windows app.

Answer (score 13):

This is the way it's supposed to be. That's called URL encoding. It applies because spaces are not allowed in URLs.

If you want the path back with spaces included, you must call something like:

```
string path = Server.URLDecode(myUri.AbsolutePath);
```

You shouldn't be required to import anything to use this in a web application. If you get an error, try importing System.Web.HttpServerUtility. Or, you can call it like so:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.URLDecode(myUri.AbsolutePath);
```

Comment: sounds good - which reference should I add to do that in a WinApp?

Comment: sweet - so I assume there's nothing similar specific to WinApps?

Comment: Thanks for the answer - best solution in this case is to use LocalPath instead of AbsolutePath since it's a winapp and I prefer not use Server or HttpContext.

Answer (score 7):

Just use uri.LocalPath instead

Answer (score 3):

Uri also has a couple of static methods - [EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) and EscapeUriString.

`Uri.EscapeDataString(uri.AbsolutePath)` also works

Comment: You probably mean Uri.UnescapeDataString

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpUtility:

```
 HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.AbsolutePath)
```